# Custom fields not showing in import and export filter

Tags: custom-fields, import

I have two sets of custom fields related to two sub-types of the same type (organization). Both profiles are active and I can see the custom fields in the contact summaries and in the advance search tool.

If I want to import a file and try to map fields choosing the proper sub-type, in one case I have the custom fields proposed and in the other case not.

The field mapper also shows the right relationships related to each sub-type.

I compared parameters for the custom fields and I can't see any difference.

Is this to be set somewhere else deep into CiviCRM?

best regards,
Guillaume

EDIT 1: the required custom fields are searchable:

[image]

EDIT 2: I can see the same difference when I try to export contacts and select the custom fields.

EDIT 3: I also encounter this with custom fields for Individual type.

Comment: so it works for one set of custom fields but not for other?

Comment: Have you checked all fields are set to Searchable? I believe they need to be set as such to be visible in Import wizard

Comment: @Pradeep Yes it works fine for one set but not the other

Comment: @Petednz both sets are searchable, that's why I don't understand what's happening

Comment: and are you importing each of the sub-types in separate imports?

Comment: yes separately and of course choosing the right sub-type. In one case I can see the fields and in the other case not :-(

Comment: And I can see the same difference when I try to export contacts and select the custom fields

Comment: The field are searchable as I can select all of them in advanced search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting the custom fields sets and creating them again solved this issue. :-{